# .htaccess redirect exression to match usename add password

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am writing .htaccess file to redirect my url somthing like

```
 "localhost/authenticate/username/password" to
 "localhost/myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=username&passwd=password"
```

my .htaccess file contains

```
RewriteRule ^authenticate/*/*/ myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2
```

can someone tell me the correct expression.
I have tried following also but nothing works.  `RewriteRule ^authenticate/.*/.*/ myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2`

```
myfile.php:
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['fn']) && "authenticate"==$_REQUEST['fn']) {
      $user = isset($_REQUEST['uname']) ? $_REQUEST['uname'] : "";
      $pass = isset($_REQUEST['passwd']) ? $_REQUEST['passwd'] : "";

      if ($user != "" && $pass != ""){
        #validate here
        echo "user = ".$user."  passwd = ".$pass;
      }
      else{
        echo "user/pass empty";
      }
    }else {
      echo "Ivalid url";
    }
 ?>

.htaccess:

# Turn rewrite engine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule ^authenticate/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^authenticate/(.*)/(.*)/? /myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/?authenticate/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2


#url: http://localhost/test/authenticate/john/1234
```

Comment: You have too many open questions IMHO.

Comment: my bad, thank you @IncredibleHat edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses to enable the use of regex back-reference.

```
RewriteRule ^/?authenticate/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2
```

`$1` is regex back-reference to first `([^/]+)`, which matches all the characters except the `/` character, whereas `$2` is regex back-reference to second `([^/]+)`.

So if user is requesting `localhost/authenticate/username/password`, the apache handler rewrites the URL to `/myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=username&passwd=password` internally.

Comment: not at all working, getting object not found and 404 error.  for localhost/authenticate/john/12345, here john is username and 12345 is john's password.

Comment: any other rules in .htaccess?

Comment: yes there is one which redirects 404 error to google.com (just to makesure .htaccess working) which is working very fine. no other rules.

Comment: when i "RewriteRule ^authenticate/*/*/ myfile.php?fn=authenticate&uname=$1&passwd=$2" put this line at least I am hitting myfile.php but I am getting $1 & $2 as empty strings.

Comment: replace `*` to `([^/]+)`, ** You need to use parentheses to enable the use of regex back-reference.

Comment: I have tried that before from your first answer, didn't work at all.

Comment: are the .htaccess and myfile.php files located at `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: yes, no other directories in my prj, all are in same DocumentRoot only.

Comment: have you set `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /` ?

Comment: you may need to check if rewrite module get enabled, if you are using ubuntu, try turn it on by `a2enmod rewrite`